# CPU is maxing one core and not using others (John The Ripper)

Tags: 14.04, cpu-load

I just built a new computer last week and have been running Ubuntu 14.04. I've noticed it only ever runs one core hard and the others will be below 5%. I was running John The Ripper just now and it would only max one CPU. I tried changing the affinity...

```
andrew@andrew-MS-7817:~$ taskset -p 0xFFFFFFFF 14219
pid 14219's current affinity mask: 3
pid 14219's new affinity mask: f
```

Nothing changed on the system monitor though... 3 of the CPU's were still under 5%. I also did a lscpu and this was the output...

```
andrew@andrew-MS-7817:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               3614.402
BogoMIPS:              6599.82
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

I've never noticed the CPU go above 30% usage... Any ideas?

Comment: When it's running a single core hard, can you also run `top` and determine what application is consuming CPU

Comment: Assuming you have installed john from the Ubuntu repository, that one is single threaded only, so john can only utilize one core.

Comment: That would explain it... And I haven't done anything else that's very CPU intensive yet. Possibly it just hasn't needed to use more than 30% any other time. Thank you very much!

Comment: You would have to build john on your own and enable `openmp` for example to make it multithreaded and `john` could utilize all cores. You could also install `stress` and start it with `stress -c <num-cores>` to see all cores being utilized.

Comment: Thank you, the stress test did show all 4 cores are being utilized.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the application that is using the CPU (`john` in your case,  but `mysqld` does the same when running a single query) is monothread, so it can use only one core at a time.  An application that support multithreading will be able to use more than one core at the same time.